# Can we redirect or rewrite a language subfolder to another domain?

Tags: .htaccess

We have set up a new website that uses aliases for different country domains, example:

- domain.be (main account)
- domain.fr (alias)
- domain.pl (alias)

The old website (domain.be) contained different languages (e.g. domain.be/pl/). Those Polish page are still indexed in Google on the Belgian domain.

How can we redirect or rewrite domain.be/pl/ to domain.pl?

We can't use a 301 redirect for the subfolder "/pl/" because the domain.pl is an alias and this causes an infinite loop on induplates.pl/pl/.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this rules on the top of your .htaccess file. For other langs change domain and lang prefixes in example rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # www.induplates.be/pl/ to www.induplates.pl
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?induplates\.be [NC]
    RewriteRule ^pl\/$ https://www.induplates.pl/ [R=301,L]

    # www.induplates.be/pl/any to www.induplates.pl/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?induplates\.be [NC]
    RewriteRule ^pl\/(.*)$ https://www.induplates.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```